How to compute the first neumann eigenvalue of a spherical lune on the sphere?
Question: What is the first Neumann eigenvalue of Lune $L_{\beta}$ where $\beta$ denotes the opening angle of the Lune on the Sphere $S^2?$
Problem Setup:
Parametrize the Lune in geodesic polar coordinates $L_{\beta}=\{(r,\theta):r\in[0,\pi],\theta\in [0,\beta]\}$ where $\beta \in [0,2\pi]$ denotes the opening angle of $L_{\beta}$. The metric associated to these coordinates is $g=dr^2 + \sin^2(r)d\theta^2$ and $u(r,\theta)$ is an eigenfunction if it solves
\begin{align}
&\partial_r^2 u+\frac{\cos r}{\sin r} \partial_r u+\frac{1}{\sin ^2 r} \partial_\theta^2 u+\lambda u=0\\
&u_{\theta}(r, 0)=u_{\theta}(r, \beta)=0 .    
\end{align}
Writing $u(r,\theta)=X(r)Y(\theta)$ and setting
\begin{align}
    Y''(\theta) + m^2 Y(\theta) = 0
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
    Y(\theta) = A \sin(m\theta) + B\cos(m\theta)
\end{align}
and since $\partial_\theta  Y(\theta)$ has to vanish at $\theta = 0$ and $\beta$ we must have that $A\equiv 0.$ Thus taking $B\equiv 1$ we set
\begin{align}
    Y(\theta) = \cos\left(\frac{n \pi}{\beta}\theta\right),
\end{align}
where $m=\frac{\pi n}{\beta}$ for $n=0,1,\cdots.$ On the other hand $X$ satisfies
\begin{align}
X'' + \cot(r) X' + \left(-\frac{m^2}{\sin^2(r)} + \lambda\right) X = 0
\end{align}
When $m$ is an integer then writing $\lambda = l(l+1)$ we get that
$$X=c_1 P_l^m(\cos(r)) + c_2 Q_l^m(\cos(r))$$
where $P_l^m$ and $Q_l^m$ are the associated Legendre functions. I am guessing that the eigenfunctions of $L_{\beta}$ are of the form
$$\cos\left(\frac{n \pi}{\beta}\theta\right)P^m_l(\cos(r))$$
with the first eigenvalue being $\frac{\pi}{\beta}\left(\frac{\pi}{\beta}+1\right)$. Is this computation correct?
